How to deploy a Visual Studio application and install Firebird as a service in silent mode?
I should deploy my own C# application that uses Firebird as database server and remote connections. Which files should I distribute and execute during installation so that the end user does not have to intervene and notice anything?
I used the Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects 2022 extension and I am able to attach the database.fdb and FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.dll, but evidently it is not enough because I don't see the active server among the services.
What Firebird files should I attach and run to the distribution? Is it possible to install the server without displaying any Windows and setting passwords from code?

There are ‘Zip kits for manual/custom installs’ on this page

And switches of installer are described here and there.

Sorry but I'm not a real professional and I'm missing something. How can I launch script commands from my C# application? What I tried: I downloaded the kit.zip and unzipped it into a folder that I attached to my .msi file. Then I launched the install_service.bat file from my C# application. I see that the server is active among the services but to operate it asks me to install a new user. How to connect to db without password in connection string to create new user? Are there simpler methods like user user13964273
? Is it necessary to attach all the files that are in the kit?

You need to install Firebird, so use its installer, and check its documentation for how you perform a silent install. I wouldn't recommend using the zipkit in this case, but if you do, you need to run instsvc as admin to install and start the service.

Thanks Mark. I managed to install firebird with the file Firebird-5.0.1.1469-0-windows-x64.exe in silent mode with the parameters /SP- /SILENT /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES /NOCANCEL /NORESTART/MERGETASKS='UseSuperServerTask\UseGuardianTask,MenuGroupTask,CopyFbClientAsGds32Task' /SYSDBAPASSWORD='masterkey'/FORCE", but password don't change. If I want to attach a database I have to create it with user SYSDBA and password masterkey. How can I change the passwords during the silent installation?

Did you already have Firebird installed (or at least, had it previously installed)? Because the installer will not set the password if the security5.fdb already exists in the installation directory.

BTW, using guardian is a very bad idea on any modern Windows.

Thanks user 13964273. I'm not a real Firebird expert so I'll take your advice and remove guardian from the silent install

Yes mark. I had already installed firebirdsql other times on my production PC but I thought that uninstalling Firebird would remove all the files and instead I saw that secutityf5.fdb remains there and most likely, as you say, a new installation of firebird does not read the new password. This should not happen however in an installation where firebird has never been installed and therefore I will be able to change the password. Why doesn't uninstall delete all files?

@L.Andrea Because it would be pretty bad if you uninstall Firebird (e.g. to upgrade to a newer version), and you lose your security database with the user accounts and passwords. Same goes for custom configuration firebird.conf and databases.conf (and other configuration files). Basically, IIRC, the installer will only remove files that are identical to the original installed version. So if they have been modified (configuration, security database), or files that were added (like plugins), they are retained.

BTW: If you managed to solve your problem, don't hesitate to write your own answer with your solution!

I wanted to thank everyone who helped me find a solution.
The original problem was to deploy my C# application together with a Firebird instance as a service (and connect to it) installing everything from a single file and single click. I ended up using InnoSetup (which I had never used). I of course added all the application DDL + my firebird.FDB database and the Firebird installation file Firebird-5.0.1.1469-0-windows-x64.exe. The setup first installs only my C# application in which the setup procedure starts the Firebird .exe file and connects the database that I find in the app's installation dir. Before installing, I check that there is no Firebird already installed.
This is the code to check if there is an active Firebird service
foreach (ServiceController s in ServiceController.GetServices())
{
    if (UCase(Strings.Mid(s.ServiceName, 1, 8)) == "FIREBIRD") // AndAlso s.Status = ServiceControllerStatus.Running
    {
        switch (s.Status)
        {
            case 4: // ServiceControllerStatus.Running
                {
                   // to do something
                }
            case 1: // ServiceControllerStatus.Paused
                {
                    // to do something
                }
        }
    }
}

This is the code to silently install Firebird as Service:
string appPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
string exedinstall = "Firebird-5.0.1.1469-0-windows-x64.exe";
string installFile = appPath + @"\" + exedinstall;
string Arguments = @"/SP- /SILENT /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES /NOCANCEL  /NORESTART/MERGETASKS='UseSuperServerTask\CopyFbClientAsGds32Task'/SYSDBAPASSWORD='masterkey'/FORCE";     
var installerProcess = new Process();
installerProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
installerProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
installerProcess = Process.Start(installFile, Arguments);

while (installerProcess.HasExited == false)
{
    // indicate progress to user 
    Application.DoEvents();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250);
}

I am not a professional and there may be some formal errors, but I will be very happy if this code can help someone. Thanks again everyone

I claimed victory too soon. I still need help. I tried to simulate an installation on a new PC. I uninstalled Firebird and deleted all installation files. I believed everything would work out. But I have the following error from firebird: Install incomplete. To complete security database initialization please Create User. I read the README.security_database file but I can't make the user open the shell. I need to be able to install it with the installation parameters. I don't need to change my username and password.  Firebird is a support db for my application

I tried entering /SYSDBANAME='SYSDBA' but the error is the same. I also tried /SUPPORTLEGACYCLIENTAUTH but nothing changes. How can I specify user SYSDBA from silent installation?

I tried to override it by copying the silent installation's security5.fdb with the standard installation's security5.fdb and everything worked. I imagine I can also create the user with sql command from C#. I tried but I can't connect. What username and password should I use to connect to security5.fdb to create new user?

But I can't copy security5.fdb from code because the service must be stopped and I can't stop it from code because I don't have administrator privileges

Make sure there are spaces between each commandline option. The error you receive means that the security database wasn't initialized with the Srp plugin, which means that no code was executed to create the user; it could be a bug in the installer (I've seen it reported and claimed fixed multiple times). You could try to create the user yourself by using ISQL to connect to the employee example database in embedded mode. Using the SUPPORTLEGACYCLIENTAUTH is not advisable, because the Firebird ADO.net provide doesn't support legacy authentication when connecting to Firebird 3 or higher.

Thanks again Mark. I didn't know about the importance of keeping spaces before the . I have read hundreds of blogs but have never read this information. I cleaned up my string with attributes: now the string is this: "/SP- /SILENT /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES /NOCANCEL /NORESTART /MERGETASKS='UseSuperServerTask','CopyFbClientAsGds32Task' " with a space before . I also eliminated the password and username assignment and the FORCE clause.

I uninstalled everything and deleted the firebird directories to simulate a new installation 4 times. Now everything seems to work magically!! I've been trying non-stop for 10 hours. I don't believe it. Thank you. I hope I don't encounter any new problems but I don't think so.
